# Checking if a field allows null values in Django

Tags: python, django, null

I'm writing generic functions (using `hasattr`, `setattr`, `getattr` ...), in order to manage and update field values for a given field `field_name` of a certain model?

Is there a way to check if the field `my_model.field_name` allows null values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this way:

```
ModelName._meta.get_field('field_name').null
```